# Can't do a post with angular cause ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've a problem with angularjs. When i Try to get elements from my database all is fine. But now, I've added a controller that i use to do a *post* called *hb2Controller* and it gives me this error:

> Error: error:areq
>   Bad Argument
>   Argument 'hb2Controller' is not a function, got undefined

What Have i done wrong? Why it gives me this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>hEY bOss</title>

          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
          <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
      <h2 align="center"><small><b>HeyBossTeam</b> TABELLA TEMPI</small></h2>

      <form name="AddTimez" method="POST">
      <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="hb2Controller">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Gioco</th>
            <th>Pista</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Tempi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTime.Gioco" name="Gioco"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTime.Pista" name="Pista"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTime.Nome" name="Nome"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTime.Tempi" name="Tempi"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
              <button data-ng-click="addNewTime()" name="add">Aggiungi Tempo</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </form>

      <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="hbController">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Gioco</th>
            <th>Pista</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Tempi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in datas | orderBy: 'Gioco'">
            <td>{{x.Gioco}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Pista}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Nome}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Tempi}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <script>
      function hbController($scope,$http) {
          var site = "http://heyboss.altervista.org";
          var page = "/mysqlLulz.php";
          $http.get(site + page).success(function(response) {$scope.datas = response;});
      }
      function hb2Controller($scope,$http) {
            $scope.addNewTime = function(add){
              $http.post("mysqlLulz2.php",{'Gioco': $scope.newTime.Gioco, 'Pista': $scope.newTime.Pista, 'Nome': $scope.newTime.Nome, 'Tempi': $scope.newTime.Tempi})
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  console.log("inserted Successfully");
              };
            };
          }
      </script>
          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed one `)`:

```
          $http.post("mysqlLulz2.php",{'Gioco': $scope.newTime.Gioco, 'Pista': $scope.newTime.Pista, 'Nome': $scope.newTime.Nome, 'Tempi': $scope.newTime.Tempi})
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
              console.log("inserted Successfully");
          });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HkGSvPdQGfDTJbAiYimT?p=info

Comment: oh god, thanks! However now it go fine, but it doesn't put anything in the database when i try to add.

Comment: http://heyboss.altervista.org/ try. Here is mysqlLulz2.php -> http://pastebin.com/7BQR2pVB

Comment: The call is actually performed and it returns 200.
I can see that the response is empty, I suggest you to check what's going on the php page. Check also on the DB, it could be that you are actually inserting it in, but it is not added on the $scope.datas and thus the list is not updated